# Notation / name for the multiplicative group of integer powers of 2

Tags: group-theory, notation, terminology, group-isomorphism

As an elementary example of isomorphic groups, I want to show my students the isomorphism between the additive group of integers $(\mathbb Z, +)$ and the multiplicative group $(S, \times)$, where $S = \{ 2^k \mid k \in \mathbb Z \}$. I am wondering if there is any kind of conventional notation for the set $S$.  My first instinct is to denote it as $2^{\mathbb Z}$, in analogy with how we write $2\mathbb Z = \{ 2k \mid k\in Z\}$.  But $2^{\mathbb Z}$ already has a conventional meaning, as the set of all functions $f: \mathbb Z \to 2$.

Is there a conventional name or notation for the multiplicative group I'm interested in?

Comment: It's just $\mathbb Z$, up to isomorphism, as you say.  Not sure it has a special name.  What you wrote is a perfectly clear definition.

Comment: There may not be any conventional notation/name for this group, but on the other hand it is a subgroup of the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers which *does* have a conventional notation, namely $\mathbb R^\times$. After the fact (i.e. after your students have studied this stuff more) one could then at least name your group: it is the subgroup of $\mathbb R^\times$ generated by $\{2\}$.

Comment: @lulu saying that it is "just $\mathbb Z$ up to isomorphism" elides the fact that *as sets* they are different objects, which is the whole point of the example.   $2\mathbb Z$ is also "just $\mathbb Z$ up to isomorphism" but we have a way to denote the difference.